# VFP redirect intermittently display blank page

Tags: apex, visualforce

On click of "Log a call" button on contact page, it either open existing CTI Task if already created (If condition) or by default opens new Task pre-populating contact field. When redirecting to New Task page, intermittently page displays blank, upon F5 then it shows up New Task page. API Version is 28 and user is using Chrome. Do you have any idea on this behaviour?

VFP code:

```
<apex:page id="page"  standardController="Contact" extensions="CTITaskEditPage" action="{!redirectToEditTask}">
</apex:page>

Controller:
public class CTITaskEditPage{
     public List<Task> Taskrecord;
     private Contact con;
     public String UsrId;
     public string ids;
     //added an instance varaible for the standard controller
     private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
     public CTITaskEditPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
        this.con = (Contact)controller.getRecord(); 
        Usrid = UserInfo.getUserId();
        ids = this.con.id;
     }
     //this method is called on click of a button and this will redirect the Page to recently created task in its edit mode.
     public PageReference redirectToEditTask(){
        Taskrecord= new List<Task>();
        List<Task> Taskrcd = new List<Task>();
        Taskrcd = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Subject, whatID, whoId, whoid_stamp__c,CallDurationInSeconds FROM Task where ownerId =: usrid and whoid = null and whoid_stamp__c =: ids and CallDurationInSeconds > 0 and lastmodifieddate = today order by CreatedDate desc Limit 1];
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+'00T/e?who_id='+con.id); 
        if(Taskrcd.size() > 0){
                Taskrcd[0].whoid = con.id;
                update Taskrcd[0];
        pageRef = new PageReference('/'+Taskrcd[0].Id+'/e');
        }
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
     }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you checked the debug log and browser developer console for errors?

Comment: @DavidCheng, I did compare debug logs with success logs (VFP displays complete date) vs blank page logs , there is NO difference, no errors from server and SFDC support confirmed the same. Also the browser logs (F12 Chrome) shows no logs when page is displayed blank. We also cleared the cache but no luck. Any suggestion would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Experts, does removing "pageRef.setRedirect(true);" helps? or changing the API version to latest would fix? The only issues is I cannot replicate this issue in lower environment so need to go with assumption that it will fix in production. Any ideas appreciated.